# Can we get syntax highlighting?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

I just answered [my first question](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/677/struggling-to-integrate-sklearn-and-pandas-in-simple-kaggle-task) here on Data Science Stack Exchange.  I am a somewhat regular user on SO and Programmers.SE.  By that I mean that I have some experience using this kind of sites, and I know a bit about their policies — however, I do not know much about the particular policies of this site.

I find it quite surprising that code highlighting (a.k.a syntax highlighting) is not enabled on this site.  I would expect code snippets in R, Python, Scala and (possibly) Java to be required fairly regularly to answer questions, or to ask questions at all.

Other questions that would benefit from code highlighting:

- [Working with HPC clusters](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/704/working-with-hpc-clusters)
- [Linearly increasing data with manual reset](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/671/linearly-increasing-data-with-manual-reset)

(Please note this does not mean answering to questions of type "this code is not working", which arguably could go to Stack Overflow.  I can imagine asking "how do you classify this kind of data with these constraints", and the answers would be *much more helpful* if they included a snippet, ideally in the language and platform that the question author requests.)

Comment: I guess we need to raise examples of usage, as the one you provided, so we can ask with property for such feature. Same case of [tex support](http://meta.datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/6/can-we-get-tex-support#comment12_6).

Comment: Here's another example of usage: [How to extract features and classify alert emails coming from monitoring tools into proper category?](http://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/4955/10337)

Comment: Not sure if a comment is sufficient, but I'd love to bump this feature request.

Answer (score 2):

For the record, there are about five requests for this now on meta:
https://datascience.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=highlighting

Let me ping a CM to see if we can enable it.

Comment: I guess it was last year that one of the moderators requested that on the meta of SE and they said they will do that and they want but don't have time for that. After a year, they almost change everything from UI to UX but didn't care about that. If you notice our community even does not have any logo :) Anyway, thanks for that. It is really needed.