# Code Snippet Regular Expression

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, suggestion

I have a suggestion. I don't think it is difficult for the owners of the web site to enable the highlighting for code snippets. It is already enabled in Stackoverflow. As of now code snippets on Data Science, seem to be ugly-looking stuff. Is it possible that someone could enable Syntax Highlighting?

Comment: I am unfamiliar with this functionality.  Do you have a reference from SO?

Comment: @StephenRauch Sure, take a look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11227809/5120235), the code snippet has different colors for functions, classes, numbers and other entities which help readability while this behavior is not supported in our community, e.g. the code snippet [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/15313/28175). This behavior is performed by employing regular expressions.

Comment: Why do you think this is based on Regular Expressions?

Comment: I edited your your question to what I think is the correct terminology.  If I broke the question you can rollback the edit or re-edit it as needed.

Comment: @StephenRauch no it's just fine :) I've said that because during my BS I had a project for autumota subject. That time we wrote a text editor for highlighting different entities using state machines.

Comment: Requested [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/308709/302377)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds reasonable. We do need syntax highlighting on the site.

Please help me with collecting a good number of example posts which would benefit from the feature.

[Converting this answer to a community wiki so that people can edit it]

**List:**

[Hypertuning XGBoost parameters](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/9368/29575)

[Feature extraction of images in Python](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/8849/29575)

[Calculating KL Divergence in Python](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/9264/29575)

[Tensorflow dataset batching for complex data](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/29306/28175)

[Keras negative sampling with custom layer](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/28213/28175)

Comment: Add three links to posts from nobody in particular...  :-)

Answer (score 3):

[Syntax Highlighting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work) is a feature available on StackExchange Sites.

This question has been [asked before](https://datascience.meta.stackexchange.com/q/96/29575).  It was not addressed. Let's hope this go around we can get the appropriate people's attention.